# MediaWiki PHP sessions on PHP5-FPM and NginX

Tags: session, nginx, mediawiki, php

I have been trying to install mediawiki on my nginx/php5-fpm stack for about a day now, I have numerous other frameworks from Wordpress, Magento to OpenEMON installed on this stack all working perfectly:

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
- NginX 1.3.8 w/ SPDY
- PHP-FPM 5.5.8-3
- Varnish 3.0.2
- APCu 4.0.2
- Zend OPCache 7.0.3-dev

If you look here: http://wiki.qubmc.co.uk/mw-config/index.php

Pressing continue just brings up the session error: `Your session data was lost! Check your php.ini and make sure session.save_path is set to an appropriate directory.`

Sessions ARE being created in `/tmp/` by PHP for this application and others.

**Nginx config:**

```
# HTTP server
server {
        listen   8080;
        server_name  wiki.qubmc.co.uk;

    root /var/www/qubmc.co.uk/wiki;
    index index.html index.php;
    client_body_timeout     60;

#    Exclude all access from the cache directory
  location ^~ /cache/ { deny all; }

#    Prevent access to any files starting with a dot, like .htaccess
#    or text editor temp files
  location ~ /\. { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }

#    Prevent access to any files starting with a $ (usually temp files)
  location ~ ~$ { access_log off; log_not_found off; deny all; }

#    Do not log access to robots.txt, to keep the logs cleaner
  location = /robots.txt { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

#    Do not log access to the favicon, to keep the logs cleaner
  location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

#    Keep images and CSS around in browser cache for as long as possible,
#    to cut down on server load
  location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
      try_files $uri /index.php;
      expires max;
      log_not_found off;
  }

#    Mark all of these directories as "internal", which means that they cannot
#    be explicitly accessed by clients. However, the web server can still use
#    and serve the files inside of them. This keeps people from poking around
#    in the wiki's internals.
  location ^~ /bin/ { internal; }
  location ^~ /docs/ { internal; }
  location ^~ /extensions/ { internal; }
  location ^~ /includes/ { internal; }
  location ^~ /maintenance/ { internal; }
#    location ^~ /mw-config/ { internal; } #Uncomment after installation
  location ^~ /resources/ { internal; }
  location ^~ /serialized/ { internal; }
  location ^~ /tests/ { internal; }

#    Force potentially-malicious files in the /images directory to be served
#    with a text/plain mime type, to prevent them from being executed by
#    the PHP handler
  location ~* ^/images/.*.(html|htm|shtml|php)$ {
      types { }
      default_type text/plain;
  }

#    Redirect all requests for unknown URLs out of images and back to the
#    root index.php file
  location ^~ /images/ {
      try_files $uri /index.php;
  }

  location ~ \.php5?$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass php-daemon;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
  }

  location ~ \.php?$ {
      try_files $uri =404;
      include fastcgi_params;
      fastcgi_pass php-daemon;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
  }
}
```

**php.ini**

```
[Session]
; Handler used to store/retrieve data.
; http://php.net/session.save-handler
session.save_handler = files

; Argument passed to save_handler.  In the case of files, this is the path
; where data files are stored. Note: Windows users have to change this
; variable in order to use PHP's session functions.
;
; The path can be defined as:
;
;     session.save_path = "N;/path"
;
; where N is an integer.  Instead of storing all the session files in
; /path, what this will do is use subdirectories N-levels deep, and
; store the session data in those directories.  This is useful if you
; or your OS have problems with lots of files in one directory, and is
; a more efficient layout for servers that handle lots of sessions.
;
; NOTE 1: PHP will not create this directory structure automatically.
;         You can use the script in the ext/session dir for that purpose.
; NOTE 2: See the section on garbage collection below if you choose to
;         use subdirectories for session storage
;
; The file storage module creates files using mode 600 by default.
; You can change that by using
;
;     session.save_path = "N;MODE;/path"
;
; where N is an integer.  Instead of storing all the session files in
; /path, what this will do is use subdirectories N-levels deep, and
; store the session data in those directories.  This is useful if you
; or your OS have problems with lots of files in one directory, and is
; a more efficient layout for servers that handle lots of sessions.
;
; NOTE 1: PHP will not create this directory structure automatically.
;         You can use the script in the ext/session dir for that purpose.
; NOTE 2: See the section on garbage collection below if you choose to
;         use subdirectories for session storage
;
; The file storage module creates files using mode 600 by default.
; You can change that by using
;
;     session.save_path = "N;MODE;/path"
;
; where MODE is the octal representation of the mode. Note that this
; does not overwrite the process's umask.
; http://php.net/session.save-path
session.save_path = /tmp/

; Whether to use cookies.
; http://php.net/session.use-cookies
session.use_cookies = 1

; http://php.net/session.cookie-secure
;session.cookie_secure =

; This option forces PHP to fetch and use a cookie for storing and maintaining
; the session id. We encourage this operation as it's very helpful in combatting
; session hijacking when not specifying and managing your own session id. It is
; not the end all be all of session hijacking defense, but it's a good start.
; http://php.net/session.use-only-cookies
session.use_only_cookies = 1

; Name of the session (used as cookie name).
; http://php.net/session.name
session.name = PHPSESSID

; Initialize session on request startup.
; http://php.net/session.auto-start
session.auto_start = 0

; Lifetime in seconds of cookie or, if 0, until browser is restarted.
; http://php.net/session.cookie-lifetime
session.cookie_lifetime = 0

; The path for which the cookie is valid.
; http://php.net/session.cookie-path
session.cookie_path = /

; The domain for which the cookie is valid.
; http://php.net/session.cookie-domain
session.cookie_domain =

; Whether or not to add the httpOnly flag to the cookie, which makes it inaccessible to browser scripting languages such as JavaScript.
; http://php.net/session.cookie-httponly
session.cookie_httponly =

; Handler used to serialize data.  php is the standard serializer of PHP.
; http://php.net/session.serialize-handler
session.serialize_handler = php
```

Any advice on this much aprecciated as it's driving me nuts that all other frameworks seem to have no problems with sessions.

---

As requested:

```
root@web:~# ls -ahl /tmp/
total 3.9M
drwxrwxrwx  5 root  root     3.0M Feb  4 15:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 26 root  root     4.0K Jan  3 11:46 ..
drwxrwxrwt  2 root  root     4.0K Jan  6 21:16 .ICE-unix
-rw-------  1 [webuser] www-data   65 Feb  4 15:06 sess_08sv9bc2ct47u0j2l3m3b77sa1
-rw-------  1 [webuser] www-data   64 Feb  4 12:09 sess_0gflq74v80c0cdsajevvr386r0
-rw-------  1 [webuser] www-data   65 Feb  4 14:38 sess_0ind5lrk1i1n3kgl8cboqpm5n4

root@web:~# ls -ahl /var/www/qubmc.co.uk/wiki/
total 840K
drwxr-xr-x 14 [webuser] www-data 4.0K Feb  4 12:17 .
drwxr-xr-x  5 [webuser] www-data 4.0K Oct 27 19:00 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 [webuser] www-data 3.8K Jan 28 00:06 api.php
-rw-r--r--  1 [webuser] www-data  916 Jan 28 00:06 api.php5
drwxr-xr-x  2 [webuser] www-data 4.0K Jan 28 00:06 cache
```

Comment: Can you give us `ls -ahl /tmp/` and `ls -ahl /path/to/script` ? To make sure the script owner is allowed to read and write from the cookie files and to the tmp dir. Also make sure you have the correct (php5-fpm) php.ini and on changes - restart the fpm-workers, not only nginx.

Comment: As requested, `ls` listed above, `/tmp/` is 777, php.ini is the correct one - as stated other apps are running correctly on the same server. I always do a full reload of fpm and nginx when testing.

Answer (score 1):

Per [Aaron Schulz](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/User:Aaron_Schulz/How_to_make_MediaWiki_fast), don't use the default session handling, it's disastrous. As you are running other PHP applications on the same machine, it's also likely that the session files are interfering with each other.

As you have OPCache enabled, add

```
$wgMainCacheType = CACHE_ACCEL;
$wgSessionsInObjectCache = true;
```

in your `LocalSettings.php` and let us know if things improved (they definitely should).

Comment: Thanks for the hint to change to using Redis. I have been debugging for days with PHP sessions which were disappearing when browsing the same domain and path simply by going to "/". If I changed href links to '/index.php' or '/somefile.php' then sessions would work again but when clicking on a link which was '/', the PHPSESSID would disappear. I'm using nginx 1.12 and php5-fpm. Now that I'm using Redis for sessions, this mess has gone away and every works again - back to how it used to work when I was running this app on Apache with PHP module.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the exact same issue. It was nothing more than not providing the right path and the folder not existing; also need permission to the folder(s).

My FIX:

1. Create a folder in your directory that has the WiKi file and name it `tmp`.
2. If you're using Windows then set permissions for the new folder. If you're using a Mac then use 777.
3. I used a direct path `F:\var\www\mediawiki-1.26.2\tmp\`
4. Reload Apache and try the WiKi install again.